# Generate a unique tinyurl-like ID but randomly (not mysql row id to base64)

Tags: php, sql, url, hash, tinyurl

I need to generate unique URL like tinyurl's: domain.com/pgDzs7, domain.com/ab4dh3
BUT (!) the problem is that I don't want users to have a possibility to view previous and next URLs by just changing last letters in the URL.

For example, if somebody creates a content which gets URL domain.com/pgDzs7, I want next visitor to get an absolutely different unique URL (for example, "ab4dh3") so nobody can't find out how these URLs have been generated and see content of other users unless they know its URL.

All I found here on Stackoverflow is to convert table's primary integer key into a base64 form. But I need different solution which is also will not generate collisions and doesn't have for/while cycles (if it's possible) since my MySQL table has dozens of GBytes.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it that's guaranteed not to generate collisions. As long as collisions are rare, your `while` cycle should iterate only 1 or 2 times, which shouldn't be too bad. As long as you have an index on the value in your DB, checking whether the code is already used should be fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution. All I need is to shuffle the alphabet [a-zA-Z0-9] so visitors aren't able to iterate URLs. At least it won't be so easy as before.

Comment: Of course, this is not the best solution. However, it's much better than traditional base64 conversion if you need to prevent your URLs from iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use modular exponentiation to map your key to a different key, which you can easily map back to the original, exploiting some special properties of modular exponentiation where the modulus has the form `p*q` with `p` and `q` prime.

Concrete example:

```
p=31
q=17
a=343
b=7

such that (a*b) = 1 mod (p-1)*(q-1)

given original secret index "id", you have public index "pid"

pid = id ^ a mod p*q

and given the public id "pid" you can find the secret id

id = pid ^ b mod p*q
```

This generates the following table:

```
id      pid     recovered_id
0       0       0
1       1       1
2       349     2
3       334     3
4       64      4
5       129     5
6       99      6
7       267     7
8       202     8
9       359     9
10      226     10
11      207     11
12      296     12
13      259     13
etc
```

up to a maximum id of p*q-1 (526) after which the cycle repeats.

Of cource you will need much bigger `p` and `q`, and an offset to the id, but the principe will certainly work.

Comment: If I have 40 millions records in table, and planning to have up to 150-200 millions then how can I define p/q/a/b variables? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Gregory this is basically what happens in public key cryptography, so you can use its algorithms and tools. It might be a bit too much for your purposes, but it definitely is a reasonably safe way to have an unpredictable 1:1 mapping without the need to pre-calculate/render millions of unique values.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a formula to get the next index.
Like: LastID*2+5

You won't have colisions or loops to check if the id was used before.

Comment: 20000000 = 40000000 + 5 = 40000005 and 20000001 = 40000002 + 5 = 40000007 -- doesn't seem to make IDs look different.

Comment: Well, what about 20 and 21? It's 45 and 47.

Comment: You aren't understanding the algorithm. Here is an example: [clic me](http://pastebin.com/1kLmQEvw)

Comment: I understand. Let's imagine that table is empty. The first element's ID is 1. Then resulting ID after we apply a formula is 7. The second element's ID is 2. Then result is 9. And the difference between results is always +2. I uderstand that I can use any formula but this is the main question -- what kind of formula?

Comment: You still missunderstanding what I said... Ok, the table is empty the first id is 1. The resulting ID applying the formula is 7, you SAVE that number so the second ID is 7, applying the formula again the next number is 19